# Apex url not able to pass 2 values

Tags: oracle-apex

I need a link to pass 2 variables but it either concats it or just passes only one value

```
                SELECT (CASE
                WHEN lms_client_id IS NULL
                THEN
                      'f?                        p=204:8:&APP_SESSION.:::RP,8:P8_ACCOUNT_NO,P8_NAME:'||account_number,NAME

                ELSE
                      'f?p=204:2:&APP_SESSION.:::RP,2:P2_CLIENT_ID:'
                   || lms_client_id
             END)
               ACT,
```

Comment: Did you find answer to your question, if so please add yur comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not preparing the url correctly. Try this,

```
    SELECT ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN LMS_CLIENT_ID IS NULL THEN 'f?p=204:8:&APP_SESSION.:::RP,8:P8_ACCOUNT_NO,P8_NAME:' 
                            || ACCOUNT_NUMBER || ',' || NAME 
              ELSE 'f?p=204:2:&APP_SESSION.:::RP,2:P2_CLIENT_ID:' || LMS_CLIENT_ID 
       END) ACT 
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ( 
   CASE 
          WHEN LMS_CLIENT_ID IS NULL THEN 'f?p=204:8:&APP_SESSION.:::RP,8:P8_NAME,P8_ACCOUNT_NO:'||description|| ',' ||ACCOUNT_NO
             ELSE 'f?p=204:2:&APP_SESSION.:::RP,2:P2_CLIENT_ID:' || LMS_CLIENT_ID 
   END) ACT
```

FROM   DUAL;